# 4 eq for two variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

can you tell me please where i have to put my starting value in the below mentioned code suppose i want to solve it for initial value -2p  for both theta and phi

```
function myFcn    

    X = fsolve(@F, 2*pi*rand(2,1))

end

function val = F(X)

    th = X(1);
    ph = X(2);

    val =  [
        cos(2*th) + sin(2*th)
        cos(ph).^2.*cos(th).^2 + cos(ph).^2.*cos(2*th).*sin(2*th) + cos(ph).^2.*cos(2*th) + sin(2*ph).*cos(2*ph).*cos(2*th).*sin(2*th) + sin(2*ph).*cos(2*ph).*sin(th).^2 + sin(2*ph).*cos(2*ph).*sin(2*th) + 0.4837
        cos(2*ph).*cos(th).^2.*sin(2*ph) + cos(2*th).*sin(ph).^2.*sin(2*th) + cos(2*ph).*cos(2*th).*sin(2*ph).*sin(2*th) + cos(2*ph).*cos(2*th).*sin(2*ph) + sin(ph).^2.*sin(2*th) - 1
        cos(th).^2.*sin(2*ph) - cos(2*ph).*sin(th).^2 - cos(2*ph).*sin(2*th) + cos(2*th).*sin(2*ph) - cos(2*ph).*cos(2*th).*sin(2*th) + cos(2*th).*sin(2*ph).*sin(2*th)
];
end
```

thankx

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `fsolve` is your initial value for X.  Did you mean -2*pi as your initial value for both theta and phi?  If so, you would do the following:

```
function myFcn    

    X = fsolve(@F, [-2*pi, -2*pi])

end
```

You can make myFcn so that you can specify starting values at the function call like this:

```
function myFcn(initial_theta, initial_phi)

    X = fsolve(@F, [initial_theta, initial_phi])

end
```

And then when you call this function you can call

`myFcn(-2*pi, -2*pi)`,

or if later you decide you want to try initial guesses of theta=pi and phi=0, you could just call

`myFcn(pi, 0)`